# Replace "name" parameter from query in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, parameters, sanitize

My new wordpress site has to receive and then redirect a GET request from outside that has a **name** parameter appended in the request. "Name" is a reserved parameter in wordpress so when the request is received i get a 404.

*old request*: www_myweb_com/**old**_purchase?**name**=Michael&lastname=Smith
*new address*: www_myweb_com/**new**_purchase?**firstname**=Michael&lastname=Smith
The redirect is already solved with a plugin, but the big deal is how to replace that **name** parameter to **firstname**. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the GET request coming from _another_ website/api, or from your _same_ Wordpress site? And how is the request called -- manually via AJAX? If the request is just a URL string, could you not simply replace name with firstname? :)

Comment: The request comes from a windows exe file that is distributed and used by a thousand people. We can change that parameter in newer versions but there is still a lot of users with old versions installed. That exe has a menu named "Register your app" and that opens a local browser passing all the parameters to the site, so the user don't have to type them twice. I know that something can be set in ".htaccess", but don't know how to do it. (thank you for answering).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting htaccess, that led me into a wild google research adventure and taught me a bit about htaccess and its "language". Check my answer for a possible workaround :)

Answer (score 0):

Find `.htaccess` file at the root of your Wordpress directory, open it and add this **AT THE TOP** (above the pre-existing Wordpress rules):

```js
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/old_purchase$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.*)&(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /new_purchase?firstname=%1&%2 [NE,QSD,R,L]
</IfModule>
```

What this does:

1. Checks if the URL matches `www.myweb.com/old_purchase`
2. Finds the regex pattern `^name(.*)&(.*)` among the URL query

   - (e.g. `www.myweb.com/old_purchase?name=...&lastname=...&others..` matches this regex, and stores the `name` value as a variable, and the rest of the query parameters as well)
3. Redirects to `www.myweb.com/new_purchase?firstname=%1&%2` where `%1` is the name value stored earlier, and `%2` are the rest of the query params

   - The full redirected URL then becomes `www.myweb.com/new_purchase?firstname=...&lastname=...&others..`

NOTE: I'm a n00b at Apache and htaccess syntax and language, so this may not be the best solution. But it works :)